# activeperl5.16.3 ppm with DBD::mysql issue

Tags: mysql, windows, perl, windows-xp

Just downloaded and installed activeperl 5.16.3.

Trying to add DBD::mysql and found that I cannot change ppm preferences. /Perl/site/lib is unlocked but /Perl/lib is locked.

That means ppm won't put mysql.pm to /Perl/lib/DBD/ but /Perl/site/lib/DBD

Will this work without changing my perl scripts? If not, is there any way to put the module to /Perl/lib (unlock the area (D:\perl\lib)?)

Answer (score 1):

The 'site' directory takes precedence, so it's the correct place to put additional & updated modules.

The other directory is the base install.  If you don't muck with it, you won't easily get to a place where you irreparably break your perl.